# each() deprecated, trouble to get rid of

Tags: php, foreach, each, php-7.2

I'm using a sql database backup script, in a part of the code I have :

```
if (!isset($table_select))
{
$result = $dbc->prepare("show tables");
$i=0;
$table="";
$tables = $dbc->executeGetRows($result);
foreach ($tables as $table_array)
{
list(,$table) = each($table_array);
$exclude_this_table = isset($table_exclude)? in_array($table,$table_exclude) : false;
if(!$exclude_this_table) $table_select[$i]=$table;
$i++;
}
}
```

I dont know how to get rid of this part : `list(,$table) = each($table_array);`

As `each()` is deprecated, Does anyone know a solution?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Why are you using php? and not simply exporting it?

Comment: Its because this script can send the database to my mail periodically (and save it on cloud storage).

Comment: 1 line `mysqldump --add-drop-table --user="*" --password="*" --host="127.0.0.1" dbname | mail -s backup user@example.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not using the key that `each` provides, it isn't needed in this context.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/8vie4

As arrays are passed by-copy instead of by-reference, you can use `array_shift()` as an alternative if you are not using `$table_array` again in the same context.

```
foreach ($tables as $table_array) {
    $table = array_shift($table_array);
    var_dump($table);
}
```

Keep in mind array_shift retrieves the current value, and removes it from the array.

Since `each()` retrieves the current key value pair and advances the pointer to the next value, you can replace it with `current()` and `next()`.

```
foreach ($tables as $table_array) {
    $table = current($table_array);
    var_dump($table);
    next($table_array);
}
```

If you do need the `key` of the current value when using `current` and `next` you can use `key()`

```
foreach ($tables as $table_array) {
    $key = key($table_array);
    $table = current($table_array);
    var_dump($key, $table);
    next($table_array);
}
```

---

Since the auto backup script you are using utilizes [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), you can reduce the complexity by using `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);` instead of `executeGetRows` Which will retrieve a flat array of the 0 indexed column as opposed to the column key value pair.

```
$result = $dbc->prepare("show tables");
$result->execute();
$i=0;
$table="";
$tables = $result->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
foreach ($tables as $table) {
     //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. You are my super hero. Works like a charm. thanks you so much for you kindness.

Comment: @Aska if you believe my answer resolved your issue, please upvote it or mark it as the accepted answer, so others know that your issue no longer needs an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You dont't want to do that within a php script. I strongly recommend to use some cronjob for this task, as far as that is possible for you.

You could create a cronjob using

```
crontab -e
```

And add something like:

```
0 1 * * * mysqldump -e --user=username --password='password' dbname | gzip | uuencode
sql_backup.gz | mail example@example.com
```

The above example would fire up the job every day at 01 AM.

You can checkout the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) here.

Hope that helps! :)